# Access a localhost server from wine on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and have a program call Construct 2 install through Playonlinux.  Construct 2 creates a localhost:50000.  Is there a way to get wine to allow me to access the localhost created by Construct 2 in my Linux Chrome install?

Answer (score 1):

start browser, then put 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
127.0.0.1:5000